# How to add custom label to metrics scraped by prometheus-node-exporter

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I am running a `prometheus-node-exporter` daemonset. I have `node_` metrics that are being exposed by `prometheus-node-exporter` and scraped by `prometheus-server`. I want to add a custom label like the below so I can set up more granular node observability like...

`node_cpu_seconds_total{custom_label_from_node="my_task"}`

I attempted to adjust the `relabel_configs` section of the prometheus configuration, but I wasn't able to get any of my metrics to label.

Does anyone know how I can add custom labels to the node exporter metrics? It feels quite limiting not being able to use node labels in my prometheus queries. This is what I can see when querying...

`node_cpu_seconds_total{app="prometheus", app_kubernetes_io_managed_by="Helm", chart="prometheus-15.0.1", component="node-exporter", cpu="0", heritage="Helm", instance="<ip>:9100", job="kubernetes-service-endpoints", mode="idle", namespace="monitoring", node="<my node ip>", release="prometheus", service="prometheus-node-exporter"}`

And I can also see a few raw labels too (attachment below). It appears the labels from `prometheus-node-exporter` pods are all accessible, but I want to access the node labels the `prometheus-node-exporter` pods are exporting metrics from.

Does anyone have any advice as to how to add custom labels to these node exporter metrics?

[image]

Comment: This is a configuration/administration question, and thus it's off-topic for SO. Consider one of [su], [sf] or [devops.se]. And when you'll be asking there - also cite you current approach for for targets listing in prometheus.yml. For example `static_config` allows for direct listing of labels in config, while others require alternative ways/